# como obtener el resultado esperado en sql

Tags: mysql, sql, relaciones

estoy tratando de realizar una consulta con 3 tablas, para obtener el resultado esperado que esta al final de este escrito, me podrían ayudar a formular este SQL, tengo que contabilizar el genero por cada oferta a la que el usuario aplique.

**USUARIOS**

```
ID  NOMBRES    GENERO
1   WEREBURGA   F
2   HAROLD      M
3   FERNANDO    M
```

**OFERTAS**

```
ID  TITULO    ESTADO
1   EMPACADOR   1
2   SURTIDOR    1
3   SEGURIDAD   1
```

**RELACIÓN-OFERTA-USUARIOS**

```
ID  ID_USUARIO  ID_OFERTA
1     1           1
2     2           1
3     3           1
4     2           3
5     2           2
6     3           2
```

> RESULTADO A OBTENER

```
ID  ID_OFERTA   TITULO_OFERTA   #MASCULINO  #FEMENINO
11      1        EMPACADOR          2          1
12      2        SURTIDOR           2          0
13      3        SEGURIDAD          1          0
```

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: hola @Alfabravo gracias por las observaciones estaba algo perdido y no pude ver la condiciones optimas para formular mi pregunta, mis mas disculpas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que hacer tu consulta partiendo de la tabla Relacion Oferta Usuarios, relacionando con la tabla de usuario y con la tabla de ofertas, agrupando por la oferta y al final contando los generos.

De manera general esto te daría el resultado deseado:

```
    Select 
    --ID /*NO VEO DE DONDE PUEDAS OBTENER UN 11*/
    RelOfeUsu.ID_OFERTA,  /*Obteniendo el id de la oferta*/
    Oferta.TITULO  AS TITULO_OFERTA, /*Obteniendo el titulo de la oferta*/
    SUM(CASE WHEN Usuario.GENERO = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MASCULINO, /*Agrupando por el sexo masculino del Usuario y sumando 1 cuando sea masculino y 0 cuando no*/
    SUM(CASE WHEN Usuario.GENERO = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FEMENINO /*Agrupando por el sexo femenino del Usuario y sumando 1 cuando sea masculino y 0 cuando no*/
    from
    RELACION_OFERTA_USUARIOS as RelOfeUsu /*tabla principal*/
    INNER JOIN OFERTAS as Oferta on (Oferta.ID = RelOfeUsu.ID_OFERTA) /*Relacion a Oferta por el Id de la oferta*/
    INNER JOIN USUARIOS as Usuario on (Usuario.ID = RelOfeUsu.ID_USUARIO) /*Relacion a Usuario por el Id del usuario*/
    GROUP BY 
    RelOfeUsu.ID_OFERTA,/*Se agrupa por el id de la oferta de la tabla principal*/ Oferta.TITULO /* Se agrupa el Titilo de la oferta para poder mostrar el nombre*/
/*El campo de genero no se agrupa porque la palabra SUM hace la misma función de agrupamiento*/
```

Saludos.

Este fue mi resultado:

```
ID_OFERTA   TITULO_OFERTA   MASCULINO   FEMENINO
1            EMPACADOR         2           1
2            SURTIDOR          2           0
3            SEGURIDAD         1           0
```

Comment: Hola raul, tu respuesta me ayudo en todo lo que necesitaba, te agradezco mucho la atención prestada, un saludo y gracias..